# merge two mysql tables into a third table

Tags: mysql, merge

I have two mysql tables:

table 1:

```
    id  name  type
     1    a    123
     2    b    125
```

table 2:

```
    id  text
    1   test1
    2   test2
```

these two tables need to be merged into a third table

table3:

```
    id name type text
```

The id is an auto increment id. the first two tables have data that are not related. I mean, row for id=1 in table 1 has nothing to do with the row for id=1 in table two. So, I basically want to write a sql script which would insert values into table 3 to look like this in the end:

table3:

```
    id name  type   text
    1   a    123
    2   b    125
    3               test1
    4               test2
```

the ids in the old tables and the new table don't have to match. Just the data from the tables need to be in the new table.
I am very new to mysql and if anyone can help me with this, it would be great!

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It can be done with something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Table3 (
  id int auto_increment, 
  name ..., 
  type int, 
  text ...,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO table3 (name, type, text) 
     SELECT name, type, text FROM (
       SELECT name, type, NULL AS text FROM table1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT NULL as name, NULL as type, text FROM table2) AS t
```

With auto-increment, we don't need to recount `id` at all.

Here's an **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6d5e/2)** for you to play with. )

I actually didn't understand what empty space in your scheme was for, and assumed it's all NULLs. If not, you can just replace `NULL` in this query with whatever default values you'd like.

Comment: Thanks so much! it worked!! you are awesome! :) (and yeah... the nulls are ok)

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is a way to log the number of rows that were merged to an external log file?

Answer (score 4):

Since nothing's related, start with @raina77ow's table, but just use two queries:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (name, type, text)
SELECT name, type, NULL
from table1;

INSERT INTO table3 (name, type, text)
SELECT NULL, NULL, text
from table2;
```

Comment: You're great ! Thank you